# How do I pass variables as variable names to a function?

Tags: clojure

I want to be able to do the following pseudocode:

1. Pass in symbol a.
2. Pass in symbol b.
3. Pass in an expression using a and b
4. As I change the value of a and b, print the output of c at each moment.

Ideally, I would like the signature to look like:

```
(runner a b (+ a b))
```

but I'm not sure that I'm approaching this correctly... I've tried changing the function to

```
(runner 'a 'b (+ 'a 'b))
```

and this more complicated example:

```
(runner 'a 'b (+ (* 'a 'b) 'a))
```

but this does a + on 'a and 'b before stepping into runner.

Here's my first stab at some clojure:

```
(defn runner [a b c] (
  (for [i (range 10)
        j (range 10)] (println i j (c i j))
```

What concept of clojure am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function arguments are always evaluated before the function is called.  If you want to defer evaluation or represent some computation or code as an object, you have a few options:

1. Use a function (see my code below)
2. Use a macro and splice some code into some other code that the macro generates
3. Pass code as a quoted list, and `eval` it.

Using a function is what you want to do 99% of the time.  1% of the time, you'll want macros.  You should never need `eval` unless you're generating code at runtime or doing very screwy things.

```
user> (defn runner [f]
        (doseq [a (range 3)
                b (range 3)]
          (println a b (f a b))))
#'user/runner
user> (runner (fn [x y] (+ x y)))
0 0 0
0 1 1
0 2 2
1 0 1
1 1 2
1 2 3
2 0 2
2 1 3
2 2 4
```

This could also be written as `(runner #(+ %1 %2)` or even simply `(runner +)`.

There is no need to pass "`a`" and "`b`" into the function as arguments.  `doseq` and `for` introduce their own local, lexically scoped names for things.  There's no reason they should use `a` and `b`; any name will do.  It's the same for `fn`.  I used `x` and `y` here because it doesn't matter.

I could've used `a` and `b` in the `fn` body as well, but they would have been a *different* `a` and `b` than the ones the `doseq` sees.  You may want to read up on [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28programming%29) if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's not the answer I was looking for, but I was asking the wrong question. Thank you for providing a path to enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

I would make its signature be something like

`(runner alen blen op)`

example:

`(runner 10 10 +)`

Comment: but what if I want to do:

    (runner a b (+ (- a b) (- b a))

Comment: The concept you're missing is that a complex operation or a simple operation are both just operations - you're feeding [1-10][1-10] into a function - whether it's simple or complex doesn't matter as long as it takes two arguments.

Comment: Lol and I can't help but notice... `(+ (- a b) (- b a))` always evals to 0 :) but I understand what you're saying.

Comment: ok, but that doesn't account for (runner able baker (charlie able baker)) returning the same output as (runner foo bar (charlie foo bar) and (runner foo bar (baz foo bar)) returning a different output

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure i'm answering the correct question. I'm thinking "if i pass a function a symbol instead of a value how can it use the value that symbol represents? is that close?

```
(def a 4)
(defn my-inc [x] (+ (eval x) 1))
user> (my-inc 'a)
5
```

I'm sure there is a more elegant way than using eval.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear enough to me what you're trying to achieve, but the following is an answer to what I guess is your question:

```
user=> (declare a b)
#'user/b
user=> (defn runner [] (+ a b))
#'user/runner
user=> (binding [a 1 b 2] (runner))
3
user=> (binding [a 2 b 3] (runner))
5
```

Note that the above style is likely not what you ought to be doing.  Ask a better question and we'll give you better answers.